# Easiest way to add iPad to Apple developer account

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, ios-provisioning

I have some remote beta-testers who are not at all technically savvy.  They are going to be testing a native iPad app.  They are in another country.

I need to add their iPads to my Apple Developer account.  What is the easiest way to get them to add their machines to my Developer account. I need the very simplest approach.

Comment: do you have enterprise account? If not I suggest you to get one, that way you dont have to collect `UDID's` ,all you need to do is just create `.ipa` archived file and put it into a web server anyone with the link can install your app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a UDID app like [this one](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/udid-sender/id306603975?mt=8) to get their UDIDs and add them to your provisioning profile.

Then use [TestFlight](http://testflightapp.com) for distribution.

TestFlight will send your testers an email with a link where they can download the app. No iTunes, no Xcode.

That is the easiest way!

Comment: Are you the real woz?